# Blocks and execution environments in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6, each block has associated with is a `LexicalEnvironment` to support the block-scoping features of that version of the language.

Does this mean that in ES6 a new `ExecutionContext` is instantiated for every block?

Reference: http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/09/es6-part-2/

For example (I use the function-scoped `var` on purpose here):

```
function foo() {

  {
    var foo; // Has a new ExecutionContext been instantiated here? 
  }

}
```

Relevant bit of the spec: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is only one execution environment per function. [The LexicalEnvironment simply temporarily replaces the current LexicalEnvironment](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html%23sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> 1. Let *oldEnv* be the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. Let *blockEnv* be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
>      Perform BlockDeclarationInstantiation(StatementList, blockEnv).
> 3. Set the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment to *blockEnv*.
> 4. Let *blockValue* be the result of evaluating StatementList.
> 5. Set the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment to *oldEnv*.
> 6. Return *blockValue*.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that in ES6 a new ExecutionContext is instantiated for
>   every block?

No, I do not believe this to be the case.

Based on my reading of the spec, the `LexicalEnvironment` of the current `ExecutionContext` is temporarily replaced by a `LexicalEnvironment` instantiated for the block, for the duration of the execution of the block. The `LexicalEnvironment` is restored before control leaves the block.